# Is it possible to know the current time in the interval of an NSTimer?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, nstimer

I have an `NSTimer` with a time interval set to 10 seconds with repeats.
I have a scenario where I'm starting the timer, and let's say that after 15 seconds I want to check the interval of the timer. I expect to get the value 5.

Is this kind of thing possible?

Answer (score 3):

NSTimer has a property `fireDate` which contains an `NSDate` object representing the next absolute date the timer fires.

```
timer.fireDate.timeIntervalSinceDate(NSDate())
```

returns the difference from now to the next fire date as `NSTimeInterval`